# taking the product of the elements of tuples based on their sum

Tags: python

I would greatly appreciate any feedback regarding the following question. So far I wrote a code on Python that generates the combination of 2 dimensional tuples in which each element is a value from 1 through 4. So for (a1,a2), a1 and a2 can be any value from 1 through 4

Thus this generated the following tuples

```
tuple_combinations =  [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

I then took the sum of the elements for each tuple which generated:

```
sum_tuple_combinations = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Now I need help with computing the product of the elements for tuples whose sum are 5. So for this example that would be the product of tuples (2,3), (3,2) , (1,4) and (4,1) which would give me

```
 [6,6,4,4]
```

How would I code that on Python?

this is what I've done so far:

```
  import itertools
  x = [1,2,3,4]
  combinations= [p for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=2)]
  print(combinations)
  sum_of_combinations = map(sum, combinations)
  print(sum_of_combinations)
  #product_of_combinations = [x*y for sum_of_combinations = 5]
```

Moreover, although this solves the 2 dimensional case, where n=2 ,I would like to consider the product of the elements in the tuple for other dimensions such as n=200 and so on. Thus, especially for dimensions such as N=200 I was wondering if there was a computationally inexpensive way to accomplish this?

Comment: What about the tuples of `(1,4)` and `(4,1)`?

Comment: hello, I updated my question to include what I've done so far and thank you, yes, I forgot about `(1,4)` and `(4,1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget that (1, 4) and (4, 1) also sum to 5.

2-dimensional case:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [a*b for a,b in product(L, L) if a+b == 5]
[4, 6, 6, 4]
```

n-dim case:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> n = 2
>>> [reduce(mul, t, 1) for t in product(L, repeat=n) if sum(t) == 5]
[4, 6, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you for your response. It definitely worked. However, in the code I have above it accounts for n tuples. so for this example, it solves the 2 tuple case. How would I be able to generalize it for say 10 tuples? Where for line 3 of my code, combinations= [p for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=10)]

Comment: Ahh, OK.  I will edit with a generalisation, just a moment.

Comment: thank you so much! I was wondering however if there was a different way to code this that was less computationally expensive? Maybe using numpy arrays instead? I'm not sure. I noticed when I tried to consider higher dimensions such as n=300 I received a memory error

Answer (score 0):

wim's code is a nice way to do it all at once.  You can modify your code to get it working by changing the last line to

```
[x*y for x, y in tuple_combinations if x+y==5]
```